# Passing parameters to a function to efficiently create array allocated on the stack

Tags: c, arrays, performance

I have a function that needs external parameters and afterwards creates variables that are heavily used inside that function. E.g. the code could look like this:

```
void abc(const int dim);

void abc(const int dim) {
    double arr[dim] = { 0.0 };
    for (int i = 0; i != dim; ++i)
        arr[i] = i;
    // heavy usage of the arr
}

int main() {
    const int par = 5;
    abc(par);
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting a compiler error, because the allocation on the stack needs compile-time constants. When I tried allocating manually on the stack with _malloca, the time performance of the code worsened (compared to the case when I declare the constant par inside the abc() function). And I don't want the array arr to be on the heap, because it is supposed to contain only small amount of values and it is going to get used quite often inside the function. Is there some way to combine the efficiency while keeping the possibility to pass the size parameter of an array to the function?

EDIT: I am using MSVC compiler and I received an error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant in VC 2017.

Comment: C99 actually supports variable length arrays, which compiler is this?

Comment: You need to mark it `constexpr` or use a template argument.

Comment: Please pick exactly one programming language.

Comment: Does the size change between runs of this function?
Have you considered making it a static variable in the function, or allocating it externally and passing it to your function?

Comment: And you're getting an error - the contents of that error are somewhat relevant to the question... the **verbatim contents**.

Comment: I don't know what is C2131 error and I don't want to know them by number, please add the actual diagnostics text into the question.

Comment: Compiler Error C2131 (Windows CE 5.0) - more than one memory attribute?

Comment: @ragoragino: Elder  (no?) versions of MSC do not support VLAs (Variable Length Arrays), which your actually are  trying to use here:`void abc(const int dim) {
    double arr[dim] ...` Also check that you are using the C compiler not the C++ one.

Comment: @immortal - Using static variables is a very bad idea. For a start if you want the code to be multi-threaded either now or in the future this is a no-no.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: In @ragoragino 's example, he does not need to initialize the array. Here a `double arr[dim];` whithout any initialization would pass. The array values are set in the loop.

Comment: What is wrong with the heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a modern C compiler, that implements the entire C99, or the C11 with variable-length array extension, this would work, with one little modification:

```
void abc(const int dim);

void abc(const int dim) {
    double arr[dim];
    for (int i = 0; i != dim; ++i)
        arr[i] = i;
    // heavy usage of the arr
}

int main(void) {
    const int par = 5;
    abc(par);
    return 0;
}
```

I.e. `double arr[dim]` would work - it doesn't have a compile-time constant size, but it is enough to know its size at runtime. However, such a *VLA* cannot be initialized.

Unfortunately MSVC is not a modern C compiler / at MS they don't want to implement the VLA themselves - and I even suspect they're a big part of why the VLA's were made *optional* in C11, so you'd need to define the array in `main` then pass a pointer to it to the function `abc`; or if the size is globally constant, use an actual compile-time constant, i.e. a `#define`.

However, you're not showing the *actual* code that you're having performance problems with. It might very well be that the compiler can produce optimized output if it knows the number of iterations - if that is true, then the "globally defined size" might be the only way to get excellent performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately the Microsoft Compiler does not support variable length arrays.**

If the array is not too large you could allocate by the largest possible size needed and pass a pointer to that stack array and a dimension to the function. This approach could help limit the number of allocations.

Another option is to implement a simple heap allocated global pool for functions of this type to use. The pool would allocate a large continuous chunk on the heap and then you can get a pointer to your reservation in the pool. The benefit of this approach is you will not have to worry about over allocation on the stack causing a segmentation fault (which can happen with variable length arrays).